# How to calculate the norm of this operator?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $(\phi_k)$ be a basis

$A(t)$ is defined such as $A\phi_k=\exp(-t/k)\phi_k$. I am specifically interrested whether $\|A(t)\| \to 0$ when $t \to \infty$ or not, but I don't know how to find a closed expression of $\|A(t)\|$

Comment: Show the operator is self-adjoint, and therefore the norm is equal to the spectral radius.

Comment: Thanks so in this case it is equal to 1

Comment: Is the basis indexed $k=1,2,3,\cdots$?  Note $k=0$ makes no sense in the formula.